# Excel help --- wants to get rid of zero value cells

Tags: excel

[image: first two columns are automated data d and e columns is my requirement]

Hi i need help with this i want to get rid of all zero value cells without vba and any manual method. first two columns A and B is automated data generated by a software all i want is to show data in D and E like i showed in the example. is there any way to do it without vba and manually?

Comment: Add a filter to your data, filter on all non-zero values, copy and paste

Comment: copy paste?? thats either manual or vba thats not whats i want

Comment: Formula will do?

Comment: yes Mirg please

Comment: When you said not manual did you mean get someone else to do your work for you?

Comment: i meant this =IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,SMALL(INDEX(NOT(($B$1:$B$22)=0)*ROW($B$1:$B$22),0),COUNTIF($B$1:$B$22,"=0")+ROW(A1))),"")

IF you dont know how to help then you shouldn't be replying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Cell F2` enter the following formula

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,SMALL(INDEX(NOT(($B$1:$B$22)=0)*ROW($B$1:$B$22),0),COUNTIF($B$1:$B$22,"=0")+ROW(A1))),"")
```

Copy this formula in `Cell G2` then drag/copy down as required. Change range `$B$1:$B$22` as per your data. See image for reference.

[image]

Comment: you the champ mate.

Comment: Every time i tried to click to accept it as a answer i get this "Thanks for the feedback Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly post score." sorry about that mate.

Comment: @YasirUzain - You are upvoting the answer, you have to click the tick mark.

Comment: oh just did. sorry.

Answer (score 1):

If using vba, you could do it this way:

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 : Delete Rows where "B" column is 0 or empty
'
Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long
' Get row count where data exists
With ActiveSheet
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With
' Loop all row count to delete rows with 0 or empty value
For i = lastRow To 1 Step -1
    If Range("B" & i).Value = 0 Or IsEmpty(Range("B" & i).Value) = True Then 
        Rows(i).Delete
    End If
Next
End Sub
```